Reshape2 Melt removes "0" from front of character
I am using reshape2::melt in a step of my pipeline to convert an array into a data frame. This array has a dimension "location" which can sometimes have values that start with "0", like "03001", where the "0" is important (these location codes are determined by others, not myself). When I call "melt" on the array, the data frame that it returns strips the "0" off the front of the location name because it is converting it to a numeric. I do not want to have to add steps in to handle attaching the zero back in again, and I do not want to worry about clashes with other location codes that may be the same but without the "0" at the front.
Here is a reproducible example illustrating the behavior I do not want:
arr.dimnames = list(year=c("2010", "2011"), location=c("03001", "3001"))
arr = array(1, sapply(arr.dimnames, length), arr.dimnames)
df = reshape2::melt(arr)

"03001" and "3001" end up with the same numeric value, but they are distinct categories. I want them to remain character values in their original form.
Does reshape2::melt have a way to turn off this coercion to numeric? Or is there another package method I could use instead?
Thank you so much for your guidance!

I think you just want reshape2::melt(arr, as.is=TRUE)

Thank you, that is exactly what I'm looking for.  Out of curiosity, do you know where I can find documentation on options like "as.is", which can be passed into Melt but is not described in the function's "help" page? A further note: ChatGPT completely failed to answer this question, so I really appreciate your response.

I went to the ?reshape2::melt documentation and in the details section it listed the more specific function so I clicked on ?reshape2::melt.array since you are using an array and that's where the parameter is documented.

Ah, I see. I'll look there in the future. Thank you so much for your response!
